# Product Page Error Magento 1.9. and PHP7

Tags: magento-1.9, php-7

I am looking to move a magento site to PHP7, and whilst the site generally seems fine, there is an issue with the product page. It loads half the page and then throws an error:

```
Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to 
Mage_Catalog_Helper_Image::init() must be an instance of Mage_Catalog_Model_Product, null given, called in /home/xxx/public_html/app/design/frontend/default/MAG090173/template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml on line 74 and defined in /home/xxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Image.php:143
Stack trace:

-#0 home/xxxx/public_html/app/design/frontend/default/MAG090173/template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml(74): Mage_Catalog_Helper_Image-&gt;init(NULL, 'image', '/a/p/apple_juic...')

-#1 /home/xxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/xxx...')

-#2 /home/xxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template-&gt;fetchView('frontend/defaul...')

-#3 /home/xxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template-&gt;renderView()

-#4 /home/xxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php in <b>/home/xxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Image.php</b> on line 143
```

Any suggestions?

I have now tracked the issue down to the following code in the template file:

I think I have tracked the issue down to the following code in the tenmplate:

```
<a href='<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'image', $_image->getFile())->resize(600,600);?>' class='cloud-zoom-gallery lightbox-group' title='<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_image->getLabel()) ?>' rel="useZoom: 'zoom1', smallImage: '<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'image', $_image->getFile())->resize(300,300);?>' ">
<img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'thumbnail', $_image->getFile())->resize(74); ?>" width="74" height="74" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_image->getLabel()) ?>" />
```

I am guessing something here is not PHP7 compliant.

Any suggestions? what it might be

Comment: I think I have tracked the issue down to the following code in the tenmplate:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento 1.9 is not compatible with PHP7. You need to make it compatible through some code edits. There is plugin available which will help you. https://github.com/Inchoo/Inchoo_PHP7

Edit your code:

```
<a href='<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'image', $_image->getFile())->resize(600,600);?>' class='cloud-zoom-gallery lightbox-group' title='<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_image->getLabel()) ?>' rel="useZoom: 'zoom1', smallImage: '<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'image', $_image->getFile())->resize(300,300);?>' ">
```

Comment: I know 1.x is not compatible with PHP 7 is the default answer, but 99% of the site is working fine, it is just this template file that seems to be causing the issue, so I don't think it is a core magento incompatibility.

Comment: Can you install above extention and try with clear cache. As you see in your error its about argument pass error. So it will solve it.

Comment: Hi, I have installed the Inchoo extension, conformed it is running & cleared the cache. but this has not cleared the error

Comment: Hi @Duncan_w , please check updated answer.